# How do I create controller for creating entity in ember

Tags: ember.js

I know I can add variables into controller and then access them in input and in controller. But if i want to work with entity, i would need to write down all of its properties.

```
// controller
name: '',
website: 'http://www.',

actions: {
    doneEditing: function() {
        var name = this.get('name');
        var website = this.get('website');

        var company = this.store.createRecord('company', {
            name: name,
            website: website
        });
        company.save();
    }
}

// template
<p>{{input type="text" value=name}}</p>
<p>{{input type="text" value=website}}</p>
```

How can be this done properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here [emberjs.com](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-a-single-model-with-objectcontroller/). One just need to create model in route.

```
// route
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('company');
    }
});

// controller
actions: {
    doneEditing: function() {
        this.get('model').save();
    }
}

// template
<p>{{input type="text" value=name}}</p>
<p>{{input type="text" value=website}}</p>
```